# Assembly conversion assistance

Tags: mips

This is what the code I am trying to convert looks like:

```
 # R = first number in input file - the upper bound on the rest of the
 #     numbers in the input file. If R = 100, then the rest of the
 #     input file must be non-negative integers < 100, and the last one < 0.
 # n = count of non-negative integers (except R) read from input.
 # n = size of arrays A and B, and R = size of array C.
 # for i = 0 to R-1
 #   C[i] = 0
 # end for
```

These are the registers i am suppose to use:

```
 # $a0 = base address of array A (1st input in file)
 # $a1 = base address of array B (2nd input in file)
 # $a2 = base address of array C
 # $a3 = n, size of arrays A and B
 # $s0 = size of array C - upper bound on numbers (R)

 # $t0 = i
 # $t1 = j
 # $t2 = adress of C[i]
```

This is where i am at the moment not sure how to format the arrays:

```
 bucket:  li $t0,0        #set to 0/i
          li $t3,         #set to R
          sub  
          beq $t0,$t3,then#for loop
          add
          sll 
          sw $t2,
 then:    ...
```

I just wanted to know whether I was heading in the right direction with this code or should start over. Any tips or help is much appreciated, can post more code if this is hard to understand.

Comment: "i am at the moment not sure what R is "   "$s0 = size of array C - upper bound on numbers (**R**)"

Comment: added some code to help understand what (R) does